# Why SVHN label data only has one digit ? (when umber in image may have several digits)

Tags: tensorflow

I am currently working on SVHN data.

I was quite confused on one thing:

Why the label data only consist of ONE digit ?

Since the house number could be several digit (such as 123, or 4000, etc) shouldn't the label be also s multi digits, or 10xn one hot vectors ? (10 classifications, n=number of digit in the image ?)

(i believe the answer to the question should be very easy...however, I  just had been stuck for days..)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is this:

"Each element in digitStruct has the following fields: name which is a string containing the filename of the corresponding image. bbox which is a struct array that contains the position, size and label of each digit bounding box in the image" - [link](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/)

So basically each row represents one digit with boxes on an image then you have multiple rows if an image contains multiple digits.